# Recommended way of conditionally rendering custom Vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my parent render function, I am rendering a list of form inputs. They can be number, slider, text, etc, and for each, I have a custom Vue component, i.e. `FormInputSlider`. I receive some data from an API, and then have an array of these different inputs to render. Doing a huge if/else block in my parent's render code seems unmaintainable, so what is the best/standard way of rendering a `FormInputSlider` component when I encounter a "form-input-slider" in the list iteration? I'm coming from a React understanding of the world for what it's worth.

Comment: That is what `v-if` is for in your component template. Vue is not using render methods; instead you realize bindings, iterations etc using a declarative syntax in the template.

Comment: please share the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

If you've the component names, you could just use the built-in `component` tag to render the component dynamically :

```
<component :is="dynamicName" />
```

instead of :

```
 <template v-if="dynamicName==='abc'">
    <abc/>
 </template>
 <template v-elseif="dynamicName==='xyz'">
    <xyz/>
 </template>
....
```